# Joining parks in Dragonvale

Tags: dragonvale

Before I figured out how to play, I opened two separate parks in Dragonvale and played on both of them. It is taking me more time than what I wanted to spend on playing a game, so I want to get rid of one of the parks, but after all the time I've already spent and the levels I achieved, I don't want to just throw my progress away. I have few dragons there that I really like and I want to keep them.

Is there an option where I can transfer them to my other park before I close it?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way of doing this. My partner has this same problem and just keeps playing her "accidental" park.

You will either have to keep playing the park you accidently created or just bite the bullet and delete it.

If you do choose to delete your accidental park, you will still be able to get the same dragons in your main park with a bit of patience (they will have different names though).

It's an unfortunate situation to be in but at least the option to keep both parks is there (if you really want to keep those dragons), even if it does take up a bit more of your time.

Comment: @Vereya if this helped please accept my answer